# What is java data structure representation of the following JSON? Or ways to find it out faster?

Tags: java, json

```
  "parameters":[
      {
         "name":"someParameterName",
         "value":[
            "value 1",
            "value 2"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"someAnotherParameterName",
         "value":"another value"
      }
   ]
```

Using Jackson Mapper. Can not deserialize instance out of START_ARRAY token for the 'parameters' when using `List<Map<String,Object> parameters;`

What is the correct data structure and more importantly is there quick way to understand which data structure I need? (JSON>Java mapping rules)..

**UPDATE:
Well the problem is much more deeper, Seems like the JSON I posted in not correct to begin with...
In a nutshell JasperReports  REST Server API accepts both xml and json but documentation focuses primarily on XML examples leaving me with big butt like here as I have no clue how the JSON request should look like to begin with. So I converted XML to JSON only to realise raw JSON request does not work either
so apologies fellows, until I find out what the correct JSON structure is... little gonna help.**

Comment: I assume that you cannot change this structure, right? If you could change `"value":"another value"` for `"value":["another value"]` (note the square brackets) you would have much easier time parsing it with JSON.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ can help in general (this particular example is going to be more complicated because `value` can be a string or array)

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

```
List<Map<String, Object>>
```

It would be easier to have this wrapped in a "handler" class that would interpret this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use wrapper classes for complex json. For your example,

```
class Paramater{
   String name;
   Value[] values;
}

class Value{
   String value;
}

class Parameterts{
   Parameter[] parameters;
}
```

This coverts json --> Java in a very generic format and also it is easy to follow.